# how to control an embedded <iframe> (any) video?

Tags: api, iframe, video, controls

I would like to be in full control over Embedded videos, just as like as i can control my owned videos.

By "control" i mean by commands, such as -

```
iframeId.play();
iframeId.pause();
iframeId.currentTime();
```

I've seen its possible with YouTube videos, they share they're API.

But is it possible with any flash video i embed?
can i find it's API somehow?

if i cannot, can i work on any other solution (to control embedded vids) in any other way? how?

Comment: You need to check your Flash object's documentation and find out whether they have an API.

Answer (score -1):

You should use YouTube IFrame API to control YouTube videos which are Iframe, AS3 or AS2.

Here is the full reference page for it: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Also you can use [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) or [Flash (Raw) API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference)

Don't forget to use the YouTube player by the rules (I mean, you shouldn't hide the player or sth like that.)

Good Luck ;)